# Hamburger "disappears" when using ||@media only screen and (min-width: 500px)|| (Im trying to hide hamburger in small screens in css (new coder)

Tags: html, css

Hamburger "disappears" when using ||@media only screen and (min-width: 500px)|| (Im trying to hide hamburger in small screens in css (new coder)

```css
body {background-color: rgb(236, 240, 243);}

.wallpapermain {width:50%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute; right: 0%;
            object-fit: cover}







.navbar {     margin-top: 0px;
              list-style: none;
              background: transparent;
              height: fit-content;
              padding: 0;              
              text-align: right}

 .navbar li { display: inline-block;

 }      
 
 .navbar.show {display: flex;}

 .navbar a {              text-decoration:none;
              color:rgb(219, 77, 77);
              width:200px;
              display:block;
              padding: 25px 20px;
              text-transform:uppercase;
              font-weight:bold;
              font-family:arial; 
              font-size: 18px;
              text-align:center
              
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
                    background: rgba(139, 141, 139, 0.685)
  }
        
  /* @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: none ;
    }
} */


#hamburger {
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute ; left: 800px;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    #hamburger {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e4bd911d22.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div >
        <button class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
         <ul class="navbar" id="nav-list">
           <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact me</a></li>
           <li><a href="wordle.html">Wordle</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <img class="wallpapermain" src="image/Webtestwall.png" alt="wallpaper" >
        </div>

 
  
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hamburger "disappears" when using ||@media only screen and (min-width: 500px)|| (Im trying to hide hamburger in small screens in css (new coder)

Thank you for your help!!

below is the html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using #hamburger and not .hamburger because [.]is for class and [#]is for id and you have id="hamburger" so you need to use #hamburger

You also don't have } at the end of you @media

```
#hamburger {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute ; left: 800px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried using # but still same outcome, as soon as I add @media line hamburger dissapears. thanks for the help.

Comment: Try removing background-color: transparent;

Comment: wow thanks man that worked. ur freakin awesome!

Comment: Merely deleting this line< body {background-color: rgb(236, 240, 243) did not work. you have to change background color  to "transparent" (for anyone struggling)